# Digital game download from XBox 360 marketplace not working

Tags: xbox-360

Downloaded Need For Speed Carbon from Xbox market place and I paid for it and it's downloaded and saved. The game starts up but during game play it stops and says problem with disc and it maybe dirty or damaged. How can the disc be damaged when I downloaded the full game and paid for and downloaded online.

Comment: This question is better suited for Microsoft and Xbox in specific. I'd give them a call.

Comment: Agreed with Adam. They will probably let you know the proper steps to take to fix the download issue.

Comment: Anything purchased through XBL can be safely deleted and re-downloaded.  Might want to give that a shot before you call support.  That would be their first step anyway.  If game still doesn't work you'll have to call support, no way around it.